# War "auf meinem Mist gewachsen" ursprünglich positiv oder negativ belegt?

Tags: usage, connotation

Der Ausdruck "Das ist auf meinem Mist gewachsen" wird heutzutage m.W. eher negativ aufgenommen und häufiger als eine leichte Entschuldigung verwendet. Vermutlich liegt das an der negativen Wahrnehmung des Wortes "Mist", allerdings dürfte "Mist" ja früher deutlich häufiger im positiv-besetzten landwirtschaftlichen Sinne verwendet worden sein. Daher würde der Ausdruck bedeuten, man hätte positiv zu etwas beigetragen (denn es ist nicht klar, ob auf Mist eines Dritten etwas gewachsen wäre).

Wie alt ist dieser Ausdruck eigentlich und wie wurde er ursprünglich verwendet, positiv oder negativ?

Comment: Das weit verbreitete, naive Bedürfnis Begriffe und Redewendungen in ein positiv/negativ-Schema einzuordnen unterminiert die Möglichkeit Ambivalenzen als solche wahrzunehmen. Ein altes Sprichwort sagt, dass auf dem Mist die schönsten Rosen wachen, aber auch vor 1000 Jahren hat der Mist gestunken. Wenn ein Ausdruck ohnehin nur eher und nicht immer so oder so wahrgenommen wird, dann nützt einem eine solche Verortung auch nichts, außer man will ein Glücksspiel eingehen, statt die grauen Zellen anzustrengen, um die Bedeutung zu erfassen.

Comment: ausgezeichneter  Kommentar, super.
Das schleckt keine Geiss weg!

Answer (score 5):

Eine schöne Antwort findet man hier [Das ist nicht auf seinem Mist gewachsen](http://etymologie.tantalosz.de/d.php)

> ...werfen wir empört jemandem vor, der unmöglich der Urheber oder
>   Erfinder einer Sache sein kann, ganz einfach , weil er nicht über die
>   nötigen Voraussetzungen und Mittel dafür verfügt.
>   Dieser Redensart liegt das Bild zugrunde, daß bei einem fleißigen Bauern
>   natürlich alles auf dessen eigenem Mist wächst, niemand anderes die
>   Hand im Spiel hatte.
>   Der Misthaufen war einst fast so etwas wie ein Standessymbol - je mehr Tiere der Bauer > hatte, desto größer war der Haufen, und umso reicher war der Bauer.
>   Nur wer genügend des wertvollen Naturdüngers hatte, brauchte keinen dazukaufen, konnte
>   alles »auf dem eigenen Mist wachsen« lassen.
>   Schon Johann Wolfgang
>   von Goethe (1749-1832) schrieb anno 1827 in seine Gedichtsammlung
>   »Sprichwörtlich«:
>   »Diese Worte sind nicht alle in Sachsen
>   Noch auf meinem eigenen Mist gewachsen.
>   Doch was für Samen die Fremde bringt,
>   Erzog ich im Lande gut gedüngt«.

Comment: Beim Mist an die Hand zu denken erfordert ja nun auch ein gehörig Maß an Phantasie. Ist der eigene Mist also der Mist der eigenen Tiere bloß, so führt der Ausflug zur Größe des Haufens m.E. in die Irre - ob ich nun Kürbisse oder Rosen aus dem Mist der eigenen Tiere ziehe, Mist zukaufe oder Kunstdünger verwende ist gar nicht der Punkt - der eigene Misthaufen soll lediglich darstellen, dass man etwas selbst geschafft hat - mit einem Trick vielleicht, aber einem legitimen, den letztlich jeder praktiziert. Das deutet dann vielleicht doch auf ein besonderes Talent hin.

Answer (score 1):

> Daher würde der Ausdruck bedeuten, man hätte positiv zu etwas beigetragen (denn es ist nicht klar, ob auf Mist eines Dritten etwas gewachsen wäre).

Das hängt tatsächlich vom jeweiligen  Mistpreis ab. Die Mistkurse an der Börse schwanken täglich, so wie heute auch schon damals.

Heute hip, morgen auf dem Abfallhaufen. Heute dein Wort in Gottes Ohr, morgen Mundstuhl!

Was Mist ist und was bull-shit richtet sich nach Angebot und Nachfrage, ebenso was mein  und  dein.

Man will sich schliesslich nicht mit fremden Federn schmücken, denn die dümmsten Bauern haben bekanntlich die grössten Kartoffeln - je nach der Mistqualität ihrer Kühe!

Mit freundlichen Grüssen

von und zu guttenberg

Answer (score 0):

Um der Vermutung, der Spruch wäre ursprünglich positiv besetzt, etwas entgegen zu setzen, vergleiche *ausmisten*. Das dürfte wohl vom Kuhstall kommen, wo der Mist raus muss. Wird der Mist nicht beseitigt, hat das unangenehme Konsequenzen. Es fault. Man sagt auch, jemand sei *faul*. *Auf meinem Mist gewachsen* bedeutet *nicht sorgsam* gewesen zu sein. Dass dies mal ursprünglich positiv gemeint wäre, ist eher unwahrscheinlich. Wenngleich das Bild des *erwachsens* einer Konsequenz wohl durchaus vom Düngen kommen könnte und ähnliche Sätze mit positiver Bedeutung denkbar sind, müsste Mist dabei Sinnbildlich für den Acker stehen, oder für den Mist, den jemand zum Bau beigetragen hat. Genaueres weiß ich nicht.

Interessant ist aber, dass die Herkunft von *Mist* nicht eindeutig ist. Wiktionary spekuliert über eine Wurzel "urin". Ich hätte zuerst *Mast, mästen* vermutet, doch das ist leider auch nicht klar; angedeutet wird ein Vergleich zu En. *meat* "Nahrung" (mit einer Wurzel "drip, ooze, fat"). Besser passt vielleicht die *Miete*, nordisch für Kompost haufen, laut wikt. von Lat. *meta*, ursprünglich als Bezeichnung für Kegel. Das passt sehr gut, falls die markanteste Wortverbindung der *Mist-Haufen* ist. Was gibt uns das? Einerseits bekräftigt es die eher neutrale Eingangsvermutung. Andererseits hat *Miete* bekanntlich noch eine andere Bedeutung, *Bezahlung, Gebühr*. Die Bedeutung kommt laut DWDS/Pfeifer wohl von einer Wurzel *tauschen, wechseln* (vgl. Mitgift? und was ist eigentlich eine Mietzekatze?). Ich hatte für die süße Mietz versucht eine Bedeutung *häußlich*, evtl. *abgerichtet* zu ergründen. Das ist hier nebensächlich, aber würde die Vermutung festigen, der Mist bezeichne den eigenen Grund und Boden, insofern Miete schon länger im Bezug zum Wohnen steht, obwohl Bewirtschaftung und Besitz oft nicht gleichbedeutend ist. Das würde auch zum Stall passen, bedürfte aber entsprechender Belege. Ohne Belege ließe sich nur aus übermäßig vielen Zufällen, ein Zusammenhang nachweisen. Das wäre schon die halbe Miete. Landwirtschaftlich bin ich leider nicht besonders gut bewandert.

Das Spiel könnte noch weiter getrieben werden und immer weiter zurück gehen, ohne Beleg für einen vergleichbaren Spruch in benachbarten Sprachen, ohne Erfolg. Nur der Vollständigkeit halber:

<sub>Der Mast, etwas das steht, ein Stall, En. *stall* "stillstehen, anhalten*, Tierhaltung.</sub>

<sub>*Med*, Honigwein, der hohe Preise erzielt, fermentiert und sich ändert, En. *turn*, viz *wechseln* (aber AGr. *melissa* "Honig", *mel-" evtl. gelb-rot, vgl. etwa Ru мали́новка (malínovka) "Rotkehlchen"? ... PIE *mews "feucht, Moos" [Beleg?] daher auch *Most*, *mew- "bewegen", tatsächlich schon PIE *médʰu; Man denke auch an *die Maß*).</sub>

<sub>Am ehesten würde *Verantwortung* als Entsprechung für den *Mist*; Abwegig daher der Gedanke *messen*, *Wage*, *auf wessen Messe ist das gewogen* (haha), aber ehrlich, *Messe* heißt ja auch *Markt*, denkbar wäre eben eine neutrale Frage der Qualität "woher kommt das?"; AHD *missa* "(Gottes-) Messe", *Mission* und dabei belasse ich es, das ist nah genug an *Auftrag, Verantwortung*, aber abwegig weit genug weg von *Dung*. Von Hbr. *matsá* "Fladen-brot" will ich lieber nicht anfangen (den Vergleich *Teig* vs *Dung* bleibt dem abgeneigten Leser erspart ... *Fungus, Mycell, Un-Fug*).</sub>

<sub>*meh₁- "messen" gilt für *Messen*, Lt. *missio* und *meta*, sowie En. *meal* "Mahl" (cp *mästen*?) ...
*mega*</sub>

<sub>*megʰ- "groß", Altdeutsch *Groß* "Hof, Gehöfft, Landgut";</sub>

<sub>Da war noch die *Muschikatz*, unergründlich, aber *Fotze* (entschuldigung) wird mit *Vagina* verglichen, für die Bedeutung *Scheide* (eines Schwertes), bzw. *Tasche*; oder *Futter* (Taschenfutter, Futteral. Wenn das irgendwie zu *Haus* passt als Nebenbedeutung neben den tabuisierten Euphemismen wie *Pussy*, dann eventuell weil die Wurzeln von *Haus* und *scheiden* recht ähnlich sind (vgl En. *shelter*) ... aber auch ähnlich zu Wurzeln die *schneiden, decken* etc. bedeuten und da wär man wieder beim Abfall, Ausscheidungen, bzw. einem abgeschiedenen Plätzchen mit Dach über dem Kopf.</sub>

Jetzt verlässt mich langsam die Ausdauer, ich hoffe das ist genug um dir ein eigenes Bild zu machen und ggf. weitere Anhaltspunkte zu suchen.